# VB.net Asynchronous http POST receive partial content

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, post, webclient

I have to use async http method to post Big files and get short response from an http script in vb.net using webclient class.

my script in vb.net / visualStudio 2015 + .net 4.5.2 is :

```
    Dim datas As Byte()
    Dim rep As Byte()
    Dim uriStr As String = "http://www.bigfile.fr/bigfile/test.php"

    datas = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("aaa=1&bbb=2&ccc=3&ddd=4&eeee=5")
    w.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    rep = w.UploadData(uriStr, datas)

    MsgBox("result is => " & Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rep))
```

The php test.php script "test.php" is :

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
die;
```

But the result is in the alert box:

```
result is => array(1){
["a"] => string(3)
}
```

Is there anybody to explain that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
The problem is only a bad charset page use...

With

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strParams)
```

instead of

```
System.Text.Encoding.UNICODE.GetBytes(strParams)
```

The result is :

```
array(2) {
  ["aaa"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["bbbb"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["ccc"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["ddd"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["eeee"]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```